# Groupin/pivoting table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to pivot a table without using aggregate functions

I tried 2 pivot's one to get max and min names but it's not working

```
Declare @test table()
   Name varchar(30) not null,
   Grade varchar(10) not null,
   Subject varchar(10) not null
)

insert into @test values('Ami', 'HD', 'Java')
insert into @test values('Ami', 'D', 'C++')
insert into @test values('Bec', 'D', 'Java')
insert into @test values('Bec', 'P', 'C++')
insert into @test values('Bec', 'Pa', 'C++')

select * from @test

select Name, Max(case Subject when 'C++'  then Grade end) 'C++',
             Max(case Subject when 'Java' then Grade end) 'Java'
from @test
group by Name



SELECT * FROM
(
select Name, grade, subject from @test
)x
PIVOT
(
    MIN(grade)
    for subject IN ([JAVA],[C++])
)p
```

This is my ouput
[image: output]

My excepted output:
[image: excepted output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CTE to add a `ROW_NUMBER` value and then add that to your `GROUP BY`. I've also changed the logic to a Cross Tab, as they are far more flexible that the built in `PIVOT` operator:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT [Name],
           Grade,
           Subject,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Name], Subject ORDER BY Grade) AS RN
    FROM @test t)
SELECT [Name],
       MAX(CASE Subject WHEN 'C++' THEN Grade END) AS [C++],
       MAX(CASE Subject WHEN 'Java' THEN Grade END) AS [Java]
FROM CTE
GROUP BY [Name],
         RN;
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you wanted the PIVOT (+1 on the conditional aggregation)

**Example**

```
Select * 
 From  (
        Select [RN]   = row_number() over (partition by [name],[Subject] order by Grade Desc)
              ,[Name]
              ,[Grade]
              ,[Subject]
        From @test
       ) src
 Pivot ( max(grade) for subject IN ([C++],[JAVA]) )p
```

**Returns**

```
RN  Name    C++ JAVA
1   Ami     D   HD
1   Bec     Pa  D
2   Bec     P   NULL
```